# Redirecting to Different Routes using Data-Groups

Tags: javascript, html, routes, html-lists, href

I would like to redirect *about* and *contacts* to their "proper page" when they get clicked, e.g. *clicking on about should redirect to about.html*.

It does work quite well with magazine, books and talks, since I just want them to redirect to index.html when clicked.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul id="filter">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

         <li><a href="#" data-group="magazine">
         <span class="span-text">Magazine</span></a></li>

         <li><a href="#" data-group="books">
         <span class="span-text">Books</span></a></li>

         <li><a href="#" data-group="talks">
         <span class="span-text">Talks</span></a></li>

         <li><a href="about.html">
         <span class="span-text">About</span></a></li>

         <li><a href=mailto:info@enyamoore.com>
         <span class="span-text">Contact</span></a></li>           
      </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* initialize shuffle plugin */
        var $grid = $('#grid');

        $grid.shuffle({
            itemSelector: '.item' // the selector for the items in the grid
        });

        /* reshuffle when user clicks a filter item */
        $('#filter a').click(function (e) {


            // set active class
            $('#filter a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            // get group name from clicked item
            var groupName = $(this).attr('data-group');

            // reshuffle grid
            $grid.shuffle('shuffle', groupName );
        });

    });
</script>
```

Have you any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine when I test it. Your use of data attributes implies you have some JavaScript interfering. (And your use of `href="#"` implies it is bad JavaScript). That JavaScript does not appear in your question which makes it impossible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: More info needed.... what's data-group? Is it a js plugin? Which one? It probably has an e.preventDefault() on click on the link.... please add more info

Comment: It should work. As said before, we need your javascript code to reproduce the issue. Notice that you forgot quotation marks in the <a href=mailto:info@enyamoore.com> element.

Comment: I would like to see your path to both index and about.

Comment: Thank you, Im new to this so its all a bit confusing. Ive added my JavaScript. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

This is should be a simple fix, you only have to put a back slash in front of the page.  Note that `#/about.html` will not work.  For the "using data-groups" part could you be a bit more specific?  That might affect this answer.